# How to avoid a lot of watchers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am running an application that is using tables,inside table is at least 900 square.Every square contains data and when user clicks on the square he/she can change this data,so as I googled it I need watchers to change data dynamically and update view immediately. I have read a lot about - how to work big data with angularjs but everyone write that you must show less information and then load more if user needs it,but I have to show this whole table.Because so many watchers,my program's one page works slowly.I already spent a lot of time to find solution but no result,please someone give me advice.thank you.

Comment: is the user going to see 900 squares at once?

Comment: yes,there is vertical scroll and user can see.

Comment: imagine that I have to draw 900 or more square,and I can't use one way binding option because after user change something I must renew view. Is it possible to enable watchers when someone click square or something like this.I couldn't find any solutions :/

Comment: I have apps with 3000 watchers and they are not slow - it's not the watchers which make an app slow - its the processes behind the watcher.

Comment: no,it is minimum 900 square but watchers is a lot, in one square maybe 10 or more because of data needs to change in front end too. when I vanished this table,current page works fine

Comment: Without a specific example, the question is too broad. It becomes a guessing game as to how to improve the code. Does the code use  nested [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directives? How is the [tracking](https://docs.angularjs.org/#tracking-and-duplicates) done?. Erroneous use of `track by $index` can trigger excessive digest cycles. Does the code wastefully use the [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/#tracking-and-duplicates) directives? Hard to fix if we can't see the code.

Comment: Sorry can't really show code because of NDA, but code includes nested ng-repeats of max three levels and tracking is done by $index, we don't use ng-init at 

ng-repeats are used in calendar like layout and have this structure
structure is something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/tcqh304r/

Answer (score 0):

This might help, every time to bind something like `{{someobject.property}}` angular will create a watcher to keep that biding updated, so first, identify if there is anything in your table that user can't interact with and bind it like `{{::someobject.property}}` (one way binding) that will save you some watchers, since angular would't take care of that property, consider to load your data on demand, instead of loading the whole table, lot of stuff but, **[one  ͟t͟i͟m͟e͟  data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)** shall get your started on better performance

Comment: thank for advice but I already used one way binding,but there is so many data it almost doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Its called one **time** binding. Not one **w̶a̶y̶** binding. For more information see, [AngularJS Developer Guide - One Time Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).\